# minimagic giving error while uploading a image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, carrierwave, minimagick

I am getting this error in rails app while uploading a image using `minimagic` and `CarrierWave`. i am using ubuntu 14.04 OS.

```
Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: executable not found: "/usr/local/bin/gm"
```

any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading the versions of `minimagic` and `carrierwave`. Also, if the name of your uploader is `FileUploader`, try changing its name to something else.